# No data connection after cloning ASP MVC project to different computer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio, database-connection

I was working on an ASP.NET MVC5 application and pushed it to git. Someone else cloned the project to their computer.

When they try to run the app it works up until there is a database call. They get the error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'

In the Server Explorer we can see that the connection is closed. We also see no tables at all, like as if there was no database.

Does anyone know how we can approach this? I'd think that the connection string remains the same on each machine? The database was created code first, do we somehow have to recreate it? If so, how?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: please check that wheather edmx or model or web.config is commited ?

Comment: it is commited and inside the project on their computer. this is where i checked the connection string. I also edited the question so that it contains the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no satisfying answer.

At first, we reinstalled Microsoft SQL Server. That alone did not help.

We did change the autentication from Windows Authentication to SQL, because the person working on that workstation still had the account details from the previous owner.

That alone did make the test connection successful. But then, we got another error when doing the "Update-Database" command in VS, which we solved by deleting a rogue migration that was there for some reason unknown.

Now it works - sorry for not offering a more concise solution.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string should be the same.

You should first disable Windows Firewall and antivirus programs (and similars), if they're present, and test again.

You should try a connection via another database client too, just to check if you are blocked someway.

If these attempts doesn't solve the problem, you can recreate the database for test pourposes, if you will. For Entity Framework, for example, search "migrations" term in Google.

Comment: I'll try the migrations, since they were commited as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Migrations don't work either and produce the same error (Network error SQL 26)

Comment: Did you tried the firewall and client suggestions? Try connect via SQL Management, for example, just to see if you are blocked someway.

Comment: In the end we removed a faulty migration and got this to work. It was pure trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is relevant. Obviously, from the computer hosting the cloned solution, the SQL server is not reachable.

If, in development, you used a local SQL Server (like SQL Express or Local DB), you must verify that on the computer hosting the clone solution you have the same setup. If you used a remote server, you must check that the server is available to the computer hosting the cloned solution.

In both cases, you can use Server Explorer to verify the db connection and access.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. i indeed used SQL Express. we already tried using the server explorer within Visual Studio and found that the connection is down. also, when trying to test the connection it throws the same error.
What exactly do you mean by "the same setup" locally?

Comment: If you used SQL Express, the computer hosting the cloned version must have SQL Express (preferably the same version) installed and configured (that includes, for example, the same database name and structure). The SQL Express connection string might include the server name, sql instance and database name. In your case, those must be similar on both environments. (P.S.> In order to avoid the need to have the same setup on both environments, you could use a localdb database). this might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#localdb